# How is the C# Dictionary used this way in C# in depth 2nd Edition?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have come across the following code in C# in Depth 2nd Edition by Jon Skeet and I don't understand how it works.

```
Dictionary<string,int> frequencies;
frequencies = new Dictionary<string,int>();
string[] words = Regex.Split(text, @"\W+");
foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (frequencies.ContainsKey(word))
    {
        frequencies[word]++;
    }
    else
    {
        frequencies[word] = 1;
    }
}
```

Specifically how does the "word" key get added to the dictionary? As I see it, a new dictionary is created called frequencies, it is empty. There is then a method to split a string called text into an array of string using Regex.Split. So far all good.  Next there is a foreach loop which loops through the array, but the next part trips me up, it is checking if frequencies contains the particular word, if it does then increase the value of it by 1 or if it doesn't yet have a value set it to 1. But how does the dictionary get populated with the "word" key in the first place to allow it to be checked?

It looks to happen in this line

```
frequencies[word] = 1;
```

But I can't find a reference anywhere that says specifying a dictionary object followed by square brackets and an assignment to a value also populates the key. I thought you needed to use the add method of the dictionary instance or do so when initializing the dictionary.

If I am correct what is the name of this action?

Comment: here is the reference you might wanna take a look at ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9tee9ht2.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx *If the specified key is not found ... a set operation creates a new element with the specified key*.

Comment: Stranger to me is the increment operator on the indexer result. frequencies[word]++; No boxing here, and this is not a ref int, but still it increments the int value inside the dictiooary, just like it would for an array [index] ++. it also works for strings in a dictioanary, I didnt try delegates (which also implement "++") Please excuse this not being an answer, more like a rift on the question, which is quite broad, but I have no rep to comment with

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
frequencies[word] = 1;
```

is the same as calling

```
frequencies.Add(word, 1);
```

if the key word does not already exist. Otherwise you override the value.

When you call `[something]` on a dictionary you get a value by key `something`. The same goes for setting. When setting a value you can call `dictionary[key] = value`.

The function used is the [`[]` operator (brackets operator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx).

I dove into the Object Browser and found this about the `[]` operator of the generic dictionary:

> `public TValue this[TKey key] { get;  set; }`
>       Member of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`
>
> Summary: Gets or sets the value associated with the specified key.
>
> Parameters: key: The key of the value to get or set.
>
> Return Values: The value associated with the specified key. **If the
>   specified key is not found**, a get operation throws a
>   System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException, **and a set operation
>   creates a new element with the specified key.**
>
> Exceptions: System.ArgumentNullException: key is null.
>   System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The property is
>   retrieved and key does not exist in the collection.

Comment: it is only "the same" if there is no existing value with that key; otherwise, one throws and the other doesn't

Comment: This does not use the `[] operator`, it is a custom indexer. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx. The dictionary does not behave the same as the `Add` method since `Add` throws an exception if the key already exists, while the indexer overwrites any existing value.

Comment: @Lee: It *does* use that operator - it's just that that operator has been overloaded for `Dictionary<,>`. From the docs you linked to: "Square brackets ([]) are used for arrays, indexers, and attributes." I agree about the difference between using the indexer and using `Add` though.

Comment: The documentation is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx , oops, @Lee, ditto.

Comment: @Lee *This does not use the [] operator, it is a custom indexer.* From [`[] Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx): *The array indexing operator cannot be overloaded; however, types can define indexers, and properties that take one or more parameters. Indexer parameters are enclosed in square brackets, just like array indexes, but indexer parameters can be declared to be of any type, unlike array indexes, which must be integral.*